# How do I reduce a numpy array to mean values?

Tags: python, numpy

I've ran a bayesian model using `pymc` and drew a sample of 1,000 values across six chains for 1774 observations.  This resulted in an array with `shape (6, 1000, 1774)`.  I need the mean sampled value for each `1774` observations.  So in essenace, the mean of each chain, and each 1000 samples for each 1774 observations.

if `x = array (6,1000,1774)`.

I need to add the mean values to my dataframe with a length of 1774 as another column.

Using fake data,

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(6,1000,1774)
```

Running:

`x.mean(axis = 0) gives shape(1000, 1774)`

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass multiple axes as a tuple:

```
x.mean(axis=(0,1))
```